# tensorflow read HDR image in queue

Tags: tensorflow, queue

I am trying to import HDR image to tensorflow for some experiment. I try to read the HDR image database from a queue, but it seems that tf.reader cannot read images of this type. This is what I did so far:

```
filelist_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filelist,shuffle=True)
```

and then I define a function try to get image from the queue:

```
def gethdrimg(queue): 
    filepath = queue.dequeue
    return imageio.imread(filpath)
```

I thought this could work but it turn out that the filepath returned is a tensor which cannot be used for imageio.imread.

Is there anyway that I can get the filepath as a string instead of a tensor?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `tf.py_func` to run a python function on the string value of the tensor.

Or you can use eager execution and not bother with a graph (string_input_producer does not work with eager execution though).

Comment: Thanks, I find that the tf.py_func accept ndarray as input, but in my case, the input is a string. Will this work?